# Устаовка ASPLinux

Tags: linux

Решил по-эксперементировать на Linux (Ранее работал на Windows). Поставил ASPLinux 7.1 (2 диска). Во-первых он устанавливался очень долго. В конце он не видит монитор, хотя при установке определяет и видеокарту и монитор. X Windows не ставится. Скачал с интернета свежий Linux, но поставить на эту инсталляцию естественно не получается. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: А что вас побудило поставить столь древнюю версию мертвого дистрибутива ?

Comment: Возвращайся на винду, а то говорят, что линукс ломает компьютер.

Comment: @pyatak :)

Comment: Добавил бы, что для экспериментов лучше ставить на виртуальную машину. По крайней мере отточите навык установки и первоначальной настройки.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте Убунту. При всех её недостатках у неё очень хорошая (для линукса) поддержка как в плане драйверов, так и в плане документации для новичков.

Answer (score 0):

А вот я бы посоветовал Russian Fedora Remix - ни в чем не уступает Убунту.
Ну это стандартный спор о вкусе и цвете фломастеров :) .
Вопросы к топикстартеру:
 1. какое железо;
 2. скачанный из инета линух - это либо лайв-CD либо ДВД. Соответственно предварительно следует нарезать, а потом с него грузиться;
 3. при установке - старая система затрется (нужно выбрать такую опцию). Большинство установщиков русифицированы.

Comment: не знаю что там с федорой с точки зрения юзера, но rpm/yum подход это жесть.  Я мог бы посоветовать mint т.к. ставил недавно знакомым и они счастливы :) Ну и мне показалась самой юзероустойчивой (за неск месяцев только один раз натыкали так что сломалось (драйвер видюхи зачем-то переключали))

Comment: @eicto и в чем там жесть? Может просто был не понят Вами данный подход? Или лень было разбираться?  Любой линух достаточно защищен от криворукого юзера.

Comment: мной прекрасно понят подход. Просто неудобно. В частности возможность зависимости от файлов в rpm. yum сам по себе, по сравнению с aptitude , очень мало дает возможностей. Для примера - хочу вывести список пакетов установленных ранее по запросу и имеющих доступные апдейты. `(aptitude search '!~M ~U')` особенно сие неудобно в домашних условиях.